# Why doesn't ggplot2 work with my dataframe time series

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series

I created a dataframe `datos_f.csv` with 5 columns (date, months, pp, tmax and tmin) from  meteorological `.csv` data.

I've been trying to plot a time series using one of these variables and the dates, but `ggplot2` doesn't plot.  It only shows the axis.

I'm novice in R, but I'm trying different methods and nothing is working.

Thanks so much for reading!

My dataframe (with 16071 rows) is:

```
> head(datos_f)
       fecha   mes  pp tmax tmin
1  1970-01-01 Enero 0.0 29.9 18.2
2  1970-01-02 Enero 0.0 30.3 18.4
3  1970-01-03 Enero 0.0 31.0 18.0
4  1970-01-04 Enero 0.0 29.9 16.8
5  1970-01-05 Enero 0.0 30.2 19.4
6  1970-01-06 Enero 0.0 31.6 18.7
7  1970-01-07 Enero 0.0 32.2 17.8
8  1970-01-08 Enero 0.0 32.0 19.2
9  1970-01-09 Enero 0.0 34.2 18.8
10 1970-01-10 Enero 0.0 33.0 17.4
11 1970-01-11 Enero 0.0 32.8 17.2
12 1970-01-12 Enero 0.0 30.6 18.3
13 1970-01-13 Enero 0.0 33.2 19.4
14 1970-01-14 Enero 0.0 29.4 19.8
15 1970-01-15 Enero 3.9 29.8 20.0
```

I used this simple order:

```
ggplot(data=datos_f,aes(x=fecha,y=tmax),geom_point(size=2))
```

but this shows me an empty image with only the axis:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You need `ggplot(data=datos_f,aes(x=fecha,y=tmax)) + geom_point(size=2)` Layers are added with a `+`.  You might want to go through a `ggplot2` tutorial to get start with the syntax; some are listed here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/

Comment: thanks so much!!   Now it works!, that was so obvious  t-t  i dind´t notice. Sorry

Comment: If you do this often, you may want to know that there's actually a neat [`plot.xts`-method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xts/versions/0.9-7/topics/plot.xts) implemented into `xts` package which I assume you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` syntax is a little bit different from normal R syntaxes. It uses `+` operator.

```
ggplot(data=datos_f,aes(x=fecha,y=tmax)) + geom_point(size=2)
```

Here `+` operator overloads the function `geom_point` on the `ggplot` object